# mongo .find return specific field only for all user

Tags: mongodb

db.users.find({}) returns all the users with all the field.

How to write a request that would return only the 'email' field for all user ?

Comment: Use the find projection parameter - db.users.find({}, {email:1, _id:0})

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Please take a look at [the documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/). You will notice that `find` has an optional second parameter called ["projection"](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#projections). This parameter is used to state which fields you want. To get only the field named "email", use this projection:

```
db.users.find({}, { _id: 0, email: 1 })
```

Comment: yep, I've read (too quickly) this part of the doc, trying things like that db.users.find({}, {email:*})  , should have read more seriously =) thanks

Comment: when add _id: 0 or _id: false, it also return _id: null
How can we eliminate _id ni from the result get back?